# Hangup Issue in SerialCommunication using WPF

Tags: c#

Currently developing Application capable of Read & write with `Test Instruments` which supports serial communication.

Using threading able to perform read and write, When the application executes more than 2 hours the app gets hangup. Normally read and write operation executed as follows:

- `Opening the serial communication`
- `perform read or write`
- `Closing serial communication`

To perform any UI update, used the following syntax

```
RichTextBoxControl.Dispatcher.Invoke(
    new Common.DisplayActualResult(uiDisplay.Display), 
    new object[] 
    { 
        analyzerDisplay 
    }
);
```

Could you please suggest the way to improvise the application based on the performance and loading.

Comment: Either attach a debugger on the hanging process and examine the used threads or use a profiler to see what the code currently does (which might be challenging when the issue occurs after more than 2 hours)

Comment: Using Invoke() instead of BeginInvoke() is indeed a very good way to induce deadlock.  You'll probably see the UI thread deadlocked in the Close() call.  There is no obvious reason you need to use Invoke visible in the snippet, you are not using its return value.

Comment: In my application a single testcase execution takes 4 calls. For 500 testcases it will takes 2000 call. Used invoke for synchronous call to update UI based on the parameter passed.